# Остановить фиксацию блока при скроле по достижению другого блока

Tags: javascript, css

Как остановить фиксацию блока(заголовка) при скроле по достижению другого блока (about) ?

```js
$(function() {
  $nav = $('.fixed-div');
  $nav.css('width', $nav.outerWidth());
  $window = $(window);
  $h = $nav.offset().top;
  $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > $h) {
      $nav.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $nav.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="project" class="my-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4 col-12 col-12-order-2">
        <div class="fixed-div">
          <h1>Персональный <br />3D-проект</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-12 col-12-order-1 mb-5">
        Заполните форму, и мы предоставим полный расчет стоимости будущего места для хранения.Заполните форму, и мы предоставим полный расчет стоимости будущего места для хранения.Заполните форму, и мы предоставим полный расчет стоимости будущего места для хранения.Заполните
        форму, и мы предоставим полный расчет стоимости будущего места для хранения.Заполните форму, и мы предоставим полный расчет стоимости будущего места для хранения.Заполните форму, и мы предоставим полный расчет стоимости будущего места для хранения.Заполните
  
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</section>
<!-- project end -->

<section id="about">
второй блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блоквторой блок
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var postion = $('.fixed-div').offset().top - 180,
      height = $('.form-project').height();
  $(document).on('scroll', function (){
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(scroll  > postion && scroll < (postion + height) ) {
       $('.fixed-div').addClass('fixed')
       }else {
          $('.fixed-div').removeClass('fixed')
       }
  })
};
```